# Does Armstrong and Archer share a universe with X-O Manowar?

Tags: valiant-comics, archer-and-armstrong

*Armstrong and Archer* is a comic by Valiant, as is X-O Manowar, #5 of which is previewed in the first print of A&A.

Are these two universes shared? The themes of secret +/ government groups seem to imply it might be likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes. All of Valient's products shared a single universe and a single timeline with stories integrated into a single cohesive element.** There was no "comic-time" as is normally used in comics. All of their stories occurred in real-time, with few exceptions. Valiant Comics was formed in 1990 by former Marvel Editor-In-Chief and legendary writer Jim Shooter. Shooter left Marvel to co-create Valiant characters and the Valiant universe with top comic book creators from Marvel (Bob Layton, Barry Windsor Smith, etc).

> - Perhaps the biggest innovation (of Valient Entertainment) was their use of continuity. The events in the comics almost always took place during the same time frame as publication with readers expecting one month time jumps between issues. There was the rare exception to this rule, such as two back-to-back issues covering the events of the same night, in this case the narration box would date them, for example both issues would be dated "December 12th 1991" if the event began in the December issue which was released on the 12th.
> - Another method they used was to take advantage of the more hard scifi setting, and have characters experience a jump forward of several months as a side effect of traveling faster than light.
> - An event in one comic had immediate and lasting effects in another. Once an event happened it was set in stone, RetCons never happened, and Comic Book Time was thus averted.
> - The Valiant universe was split into two time periods, the modern day, and the 41st century, with events in the former having effects on the latter. All in all, the formula worked, attracting many fans with its refreshing and unique style, and Valiant sold over 80 million comics in its first 5 years, becoming the third highest selling comic book company (after of course, Marvel and DC, the big two).

[image]